# Angular 10 - Create Custom array

Tags: arrays, angular

We have to pass data in request in below format :

> insArray[0][INSID]: 806542
>
> insArray[0][AMOUNT]: 4050.00
>
> dueDateArr[0][INSID]: 806542
>
> dueDateArr[0][DUEDATE]: 2021-08-25

But using angular we are unable to achieve it. Please help.

We are using the following Code :

```
let maindata = [];
this.installmentData.forEach((item, key: number) => {
  if(item.editMode == true){
    let data = [];
    data['insArray'][key]['INSID'] = item.ID;
    data['insArray'][key]['AMOUNT'] = item.INSTALLMENTAMOUNT;
    data['dueDateArr'][key]['INSID'] = item.ID;
    data['dueDateArr'][key]['DUEDATE'] = item.INSTALLMENTDUEDATE;
    maindata.push(data)
  }
  
});
```

We are facing issue at [Key], console showing error as below

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')

Comment: This looks like a bit of a php implementation. Unfortunately this doesn’t work in javascript. To do this, you’ll need an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we have created Custom code and it's Working.

```
let insArray = [];
let dueDateArr = [];
this.installmentData.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.editMode == true){
        insArray.push({'INSID': item.ID, 'AMOUNT': item.INSTALLMENTAMOUNT });
        dueDateArr.push({'INSID': item.ID, 'DUEDATE': item.INSTALLMENTDUEDATE })
  }

});

const maindata = {
  insArray: insArray,
  dueDateArr: dueDateArr
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let maindata = [];
    this.installmentData.forEach((item, key: number) => {
    if(item.editMode == true){
         let data = {};
         data['insArray'] = [];
         data['dueDateArr'] = [];
         data['insArray'].push({'INSID': item.ID, 'AMOUNT': item.INSTALLMENTAMOUNT });
         data['dueDateArr'].push({'INSID': item.ID, 'DUEDATE': item.INSTALLMENTDUEDATE });
         maindata.push(data)
  }
  
});
```

You can use like this above. Because javascript expects an object there and this stuff looks like a PHP code. I mean the associated array in PHP. So the structure is like an array containing objects.